# Efficiency Comparison: (condition1 && condition2) vs. if (condition1) { if (condition2) }

Tags: c#, performance

Hello fellow developers,

I have a question regarding the efficiency of two different approaches in conditional statements. I am trying to determine which option is faster between the following two scenarios:

1.Using the logical operator && to combine two conditions within a single if statement: if (condition1 && condition2)

2.Utilizing nested if statements to evaluate the conditions separately:

```
if (condition1) {
   if (condition2) {
      // Code block executed if both conditions are true
   }
}
```

My goal is to optimize my code and ensure that I am using the most efficient approach in terms of execution time. Therefore, I would greatly appreciate your insights on the performance implications of these two alternatives.

Specifically, I am interested in understanding any potential differences in terms of computational overhead, short-circuit evaluation behavior, and overall execution speed.

If you have any experience or knowledge regarding this topic, or if you can point me to relevant resources, I would be grateful for your assistance. Thank you in advance!

Comment: The difference, even when you run this code a billion times, will still be less than you took to write this question. See also: https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Comment: Do you come from a PHP background? Because that ecosystem tends to pay a lot of attention to micro-optimizations that don't matter. Readability of your code is way more important. They're probably compiled to the same IL anyway. But if you really want to know: benchmark both approaches.

Comment: **Is this the slowest part of your code?**

Comment: if the goal was truly a micro-optimization, actual measurements would be required, or at least an analysis of compiler output.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It doesn't make any difference.  The `&&` operator is short-circuiting, meaning that the right-hand side isn't executed if the left-hand side is `false`.

With the short-circuiting, `if (A && B) ...` works exactly like `if (A) if (B) ...`, and the compiler knows this.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for (micro) optimization you have **three** main options for `if (option1 && option2) {...}`:

1. Check `option1`, and then `option2` if required.
2. Check `option2`, and then `option1` if required.
3. Compute both `option1` and `option2` and then check for `true`.

If one of `option` is expensive, check it *second* (if other option is `false` you don't have to check it):

```
if (cheapOption && expensiveOption) { ... }
```

Please note, that *nested* `if` *equals* to `&&` and doesn't improve performance.

In case you have *two cheap options* and you still look for optimization, try `&` instead of `&&` in order to get
rid of extra `if` (and possible problems with CPU branch prediction):

```
if (cheapOption1 & cheapOption2) { ... }
```